# Free will and determinism

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

If God knows everything including the future, then we have no free will and if he doesn't, it’s a flaw of him and it's in contradiction with God's definition. How can we get away from this conflict?

Comment: Even if God knows the future it does not mean he *forces* it to happen, oftentimes we also know what a toddler would do, but she does it of her own will nonetheless. See [SEP, Foreknowledge and Free Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/free-will-foreknowledge/) for discussion.

Comment: Free will can be pictured as related to decision making with our subjective lack of complete knowledge, even in a deterministic universe. In the case of a deity, this can be related to an overall outcome justifying local temporary harms for net benefits only a deity might fully perceive. To think a small human brain can fully grasp the perspective of a deity, is surely hubris.